# XNA does not respond to changes in code

Tags: c#, xna

Most simply explained, when I edit, delete, or add code into my XNA project, it does not respond. This is to say that I can comment out the entire Update method of my game and it will run as usual. This also means that the game is stuck at a certain time in development, and can not be edited. I've tried reopening my project and it does not help. I've had this problem before and it is incredibly infuriating and frustrating.

http://puu.sh/1kD6P
This is an image where I have commented out the Update method and would normally never be able to run with 66 errors. But it does run.

In the past I have had to create new projects and drag all of my art assets over and copies of the code. That is the only way I know to fix it, but this has happened with every one of my projects (even on a different computer before).

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Check your configuration manager. Make sure the project's build is enabled.

Comment: @JordanMcGraw You shouldn't put 'Solved' in the title. Accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the most appropriate answer (You can even answer your own question for future visitors who may have the same problem as you)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rebuilding it from the build menu, not just clicking the debug button?

Comment: Maybe try deleting the game.exe from the bin/obj folder and rebuilding. I've run into this before and can't recall exactly how I solved it...

Comment: Cameron Scully, that worked. By deleting the bin folder and rebuilding, it began working as normal. Thank you for the assistance.